# The concept of the Visual C++ filter structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, filter, project

I am quiet confused with the way Visual Studio 2013 handles the project structure for Visual C++ projects. It seems that Visual Studio 2013 uses some kind of a "filter structure" to organize the project. But I did not find anything about the reason for this structure. **Why is this filter structure** and not just a simple folder structure as in any other IDE? And why is there completely no documentation on MSDN about this kind of structure? The best I could find was [Project and Solution Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx0cxhaw.aspx) and the only thing it seems to say about filter is

> Projname.vcxproj.filters: The filters file. It specifies where to put a file that is added to the solution. For example, a .h file is put in the Header Files node.

Comment: My advice: just ignore the filters and let it do its default behavior of dumping all your cpps into one filter and all your headers into another. Why should you need to triplicate the same organizational scheme in the filesystem, the namespace structure, *and* a filter set?

Comment: Of course, you could also do the opposite and dump all your files in one filesystem folder and use the filters to organize them instead, but having the organization in the filesystem is more portable, prevents filename collisions, and also makes it easier to do things with the VCS.

Comment: It is simply a virtual folder structure, only meant to organize the view of your project.  You can freely drag a file from one folder to another without it affecting the disk storage at all.  Why they did it this way, or used the term "filter", is a question that would be asked 21 years too late.  Floppy disks and a lack of reliable source control surely had something to do with it :)